# jQuery - Need to use variable from first function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Uber Noob but I thought I was close.

```
var markers = $j('span.marker');

$j(markers).each(function () { //function to store original marker positions 
    var startOrigin = $j(this).css('margin-left');

});

$j("a.timeline-view").click(function () { //function to return markers to stored positions
    $j(markers).each(function () {

        $j(this).animate({
            marginLeft: startOrigin
        })

    });
});
```

Second function can't find the var??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $j == alias to jquery

The solution to your problem is using the jquery `.data('name', val)` to store the value bound to an element and then retrieve it with `.data('name')` when necessary.

```
$j(markers).each(function(){ //function to store original marker positions 

       $j(this).data('startOrigin', $j(this).css('margin-left'));

});

$j("a.timeline-view").click( function() { //function to return markers to stored positions
    $j(markers).each(function(){
        var marker = $j(this);
        marker.animate({marginLeft : marker.data('startOrigin') })
    });         
});
```

check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ for more info on using jQuery data

Comment: Or even just `markers.each`, give that it is a jQuery selection already.

Comment: haaaaaamazing. Will research .data().

Comment: cheers, also remember about caching jquery objects if you use them few times - every time you do $(...) you create a new jquery object wrapper which takes some memory/time - if you use $(this) multiple times in one scope it's good to cache it to a variable like `var el = $(this)` and then use `el` in place of `$(this)`. Same applies if you use any other selector multiple times - always cache! It'll make your code much more readable :) (edited to include what I mean)

Comment: So even for that tiny block of code its worth caching? or only if I have 1000 lines of it. or shut up and always cache from this point on?

Comment: @Adman it is worth it - even if the gain will be insignificant it'll help you to make it a habit and imo will make the code more readable and maintainable - if this would ever change to something else (like $(this).parent() or whatever) you'd have to change it only in one place. So as I've wrote - it's a good habit to do it this way :)

Answer (score 1):

To explain why your code doesn't work...

A function in Javascript has in scope all variables that were declared in containing functions or in that function.  Using the `var` keyword sets a variable to the current scope.  In your example, `startOrigin` is only in the scope of the first function.  If you put it in the parent scope, all the functions in your example will have it in their scope:

```
var markers = $j('span.marker');
var startOrigin;  // declare the variable in this scope

markers.each(function () { //function to store original marker positions 
    startOrigin = $j(this).css('margin-left'); // use the parent scope
});

$j("a.timeline-view").click(function () { //function to return markers to stored positions
    markers.each(function () {

        $j(this).animate({
            marginLeft: startOrigin // use parent scope
        })

    });
});
```

Note, however, that this example is kind of broken anyway.  You are looping through the whole set of markers, overwriting the `startOrigin` each time.  You need to use `data` as Tom Tu said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804933/jquery-need-to-use-variable-from-first-function-inside-another-function/4804951#4804951) to set data for an individual DOM element.